# Python: Allocated memory doesn't get released after execution

Tags: python, memory, pickle

I'm using pickle to load a big matrix in memory. The first time I run the script it takes about 14s to load the entire object. Subsequent run, instead, take just 4s. It seems like the object gets loaded in memory and not released after execution. Is this normal? Shouldn't the garbage collector release the object as soon as it's not referenced?

I tried different times with different files and the results are always the same.

This is the code I used to test the described behavior:

```py
def load():
    with open('batch-0', 'rb') as read:
        data = pickle.load(read)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cProfile.run('load()')
```

Comment: Are you sure that this is not related to your OS caching the file access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have discovered is called the file-system cache. When a file is read, the operating system has to load the pages of a file into memory. The operating system can retain the loaded pages in its file-system cache, in the hope that if they are needed again, they won't have to be loaded from the slower levels of the memory hierarchy. It is possible to tell the operating system to not retain the file after it has been read. The proper application of this is for preventing backup scans from trashing the file-system cache.